# What are these two order workflow systems called?

Tags: terminology, workflow

The scenario: in the current state, users are funneled into three business-defined workflows. User research indicates that customers want the ability to define their own workflows and make them as customized as possible.

Two models that I am researching are:

1. A workflow engine space, where an admin user designs the custom flows that orders will flow through. This could work well for customers who need some customization, but not for every order.
2. A JIRA-like experience, where instead of an order moving from queue to queue in a pre-defined flow, users can change an order status to send it on to the next needed user. This allows for flexibility on every order and can skip unnecessary steps.

My question is: What are these two options called in UX vernacular? I'm fine with calling the first one a "workflow engine" (the audience is technical), but is there a better term? And what would you call the overall experience of the second option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description given, I would think that

1. is a [**Workflow Management System**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_management_system) *and*
2. is Ticket or [**Issue Tracking System**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking_system).

Those are not specific UX terms though, but maybe this info helps to dig deeper?